# Custom Visualizer for EASTL VS2012 / 2013

Tags: debuggervisualizer, eastl

I got EASTL from here - https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL

For debugging, I'm writing custom visualizer VS2012/2013.

"eastl::vector" works fine but "eastl::map" doesn't.

Here is my code

```
<Type Name="eastl::map&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{size = {mnSize}}}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[size]">mnSize</Item>
        <Item Name="[comp]">mCompare</Item>
        <TreeItems>
            <Size>mnSize</Size>
            <HeadPointer>mAnchor.mpNodeParent</HeadPointer>
            <LeftPointer>mpNodeLeft</LeftPointer>
            <RightPointer>mpNodeRight</RightPointer>
            <ValueNode>(node_type*)this-&gt;mValue</ValueNode>
        </TreeItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

It looks like VS doesn't recognize "node_type"

Thanks for responding.

Comment: It just shows the default information(not customized). I've figured out it happens when bugs in natvis file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for EASTL.

It turned out that I was using an old version of `EASTL.natvis`. This one works for me: https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/doc/EASTL.natvis

The file you have to replace is in:

```
%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Visualizers
```

(Just change 2015 to whatever version of VS you are using)